# Snackbar not moving FAB that placed inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout

There is a scheme that describes view hierarchy of my application.

[image: Example]

And some XML

**MainActivity**

```
. CoordinatorLayout
  . FrameLayout <- ContentFragment inserted here
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  . AppBarLayout
    . Toolbar
```

**ContentFragment**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_white_36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hint_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/empty_dates_list"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

With this code I make `SnackBar`:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(
        mainActivity.getCoordinatorLayout(),
        R.string.date_removed,
        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

**My problem** is that `fab` is not moving up by `SnackBar` that I make in ContentFragment

I also tried point `fab` as view for `Snackbar` but it has not brought results.

Comment: wrap the content of Framelayout with a CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `CoordinatorLayout` to avoid this issue because `CoordinatorLayout` alone properly coordinates layout changes caused by its child views.

To solve your issue, simply move the `FloatingActionButton` from the fragment layout to the MainActivity layout. Or if you intend to use the `FloatingActionButton` in the fragment itself, then set the parent view of the fragment to be a `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: Good answer. Now I moved `FloatingActionButton` to `MainActivity` and make a getter for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, `FloatingActionButton` should be a child of `CoordinatorLayout`. Yours is a child of `FrameLayout`.

Comment: And there is no way to force it to work with sub-views?